# Error while running docker sonarscanner begin command

Tags: windows, docker, sonarqube, asp.net-core-3.1, sonarscanner

I pulled the latest docker image for sonarqube and the image runs fine. The sonarqube server is listening at localhost:9000. When I run the `dotnet sonarscanner begin` to analyze asp.net Core 3.1 project, after some time, I get timeout error. Below is the log from the command

```
Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
18:47:29.653  Updating build integration targets...
18:49:09.803  Failed to request and parse 'http://localhost:9000/api/server/version': The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
18:49:09.811  The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
18:49:09.814  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

The API request works fine through Postman. What could cause the failure?

Comment: Do you by any chance run this dotnet sonarscanner from a container as well?

Comment: @raspy: No, I run it from the Windows console

Answer (score 0):

After I try to change port 9000 to 8000 and retry and it worked!

```
ports:
  - "8000:9000"
```